# Javascript ADO recordset open method not working

Tags: javascript, ado, recordset

I have the following code in an html page in a Javascript tag:

```
        var adOpenDynamic = 2
var adLockOptimistic = 3
var conn_str = 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=G:/path_to_myDB.mdb'
        var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open(conn_str)
```

and this is a the beginning of a function that is called from the onload event of the html  :

```
  var PassNbrAppel = new Array();
  var i=1
  var rsPass = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  SQLpass = 'SELECT Avis.[Numéro Passerelle], Count(Avis.[Numéro Passerelle]) AS [CompteDeNuméro Passerelle] FROM Avis  WHERE (((Avis.[Date Appel])>#10/19/2011# And (Avis.[Date Appel])<#11/07/2011#) AND (Avis.[Numéro Passerelle] IS NOT NULL)) GROUP BY Avis.[Numéro Passerelle] ORDER BY Val(Avis.[Numéro Passerelle]);'

  rsPass.open(SQLpass, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic)

  rs2arr(rsPass,arrPass)      

  rs.close()
```

I get the following error message (translated from french): "no value given for one or more of the required parameters" and the line number is pointing to       `rsPass.open(SQLpass, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic)`
I keep on re-checking to see if there is a mistake in the code but I can't seem to find anything wrong...

I took bits of code from [here](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2005/7/14/13942/7643)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the special characters in my SQL statement. Instead of trying to make it work with the "é" I changed the feild names so they dont have special characters. So much for French pride...